# Calculate p-value of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I want to calculate $p$-values by using the statistics program R.

I want to test multiple groups to a placebo group and thus I want to test the nullhypothesis $H^{11}_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_2, \ldots H^{1m}_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_m$. My test statistics $T^1,\ldots,T^m$, where $T^1$ is the test statistic to test $H^{11}$ and so on, are asymptotically normal distributed and my vector of test statistics $(T^1,\ldots,T^m)$ has multivariate normal distribution with mean $\mu=(0,...,0)$ and a Covariance-matrix Cov under the nullhypothesis. 
Let's say $m=3$ and $\mu=(0,0,0)$ and 
\begin{align}
Cov = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.5  & 0.1
\\
0.5 & 1 & 0.1
\\
0.1 & 0.1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Now I've for example observed $T_1 = 0.2, T_2=1.3, T_4=-0.4$.
I've thought about something like

$$p_1 = 1-pmvnorm(lower=(-T_1,-Inf,-Inf),
upper=(T_1,Inf,Inf),mean=\mu,sigma=Cov).$$

But I'd get the same $p_1$ for any Covariance-Matrix with diagonal elements equal to 1 and this obviously seems kinda false since the correlation between the test statistics aren't considered. But I actually don't know how else to calculate the $p$-value. So any advice would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: This question needs clarification: what is $R$? What are the relationships between the $t_i$ and the $T^i$?  What is the hypothesis to which the p-value is associated?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very good at drawing in 3 dimensions, so here is a 2D view of what you're calculating with that definition of $p_1$:

[image]

This is a rectangular region going to infinity and just touching the observed point $(T_1, T_2, T_3)$ at the corner. While that is certainly a value that can be calculated, it is not particularly meaningful.

It is much more common to construct a hypothesis test by calculating something like this:

[image]

Where the measure of the orange region is now the probability that a random point would have been "less likely" (e.g. have a lower probability density) than $(T_1, T_2, T_3)$. This can also be interpreted as the probability that a random point would be further from the origin in the the [Mahalanobis metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).

The formal test statistic is then:

$$ d = \sqrt{({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})^\mathrm{T}{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})} $$

Where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix, $\Sigma^{-1}$ is the precision matrix, and $\mathbf{x}$ is the vector $(T_1, T_2, T_3)$ in your notation. If true population parameters $\mu$ and $Sigma$ are known then $d^2 \sim \chi^2_1$ (read as $d^2$ has the Chi-square distribution with one degree of freedom). If, on the other hand, $\mu$ and $Sigma$ are empirical estimates from the same sample, then $d^2$ has the [Hotelling's T-squared distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution)

Of course, only *you* can know exactly what hypothesis you want to test. I'm just showing you one common way that other people have approached this problem, but I can't know your specific situation in detail; I'm just guessing. Think carefully about which definition is most useful for what you are trying to accomplish!